# What type of fastener is this?

Tags: fasteners

Used to connect the chain for a window actuator to a U-shaped window bracket.

The threaded end screws into a bolt hole (M5.5 female thread) on one side of the U-bracket. The tip of the fastener fits into a 3mm diameter slot on the other side.

The end of the chain pushes and pulls perpendicular to the axis of the fastener on the unthreaded section between the two connections.

**Dimensions:** Total length: **34mm**.
Threaded section length: **6mm**.
Unthreaded section: **3mm** diameter.
Threaded section: **5.5mm** diameter.

[image]

**What type of fastener is this, and how do I go about procuring a replacement, short of resorting to a bespoke service?**

The unthreaded section can be thicker to some degree, or be threaded, as long as there is a 3mm diameter tip of at least 4mm length to connect to that side of the bracket.

For example, a M5.5 bolt with a 3mm diameter dogpoint would do the job. However, as far as I understand, there are no bolts standardized to a M5.5 diameter.

Comment: You'll need a window and door parts catalog. I have two - one is 1470 pages and the other about 900 pages. Look under chain actuators or chain openers. Then by brand and manual/electric. Strand would be my first guess based on your description of the yoke. Can you post photos of entire actuator, and where you are located (country).

Answer (score 2):

It is a pin with a threaded head.

A normal bolt would not work in many chains that go through restricted passages, so the head in this case is designed to sit flush with the surface.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't seem to find a replacement for the one in the image, so do you know of any solutions to replacing it?

Comment: Contact the manufacturer of the window, or the manufacturer of the chain, or get them made, remember they probably have hardening on the pin...

Comment: Unfortunately, the brackets (and associated fasteners) are no longer being manufactured. I guess I'll have to go the bespoke route if no other solution is found.

Comment: Or make one in about two minutes. Requires bolt, tap, hacksaw, drill, pin and superglue or epoxy. Or just buy a bracket from somebody with the pin. If this is a top-hung arrangement, it just holds the fixed end of the chain.

Comment: I would need a M5.5 bolt for that, but I'm not aware of anyone who supplies these.